# Centos 8 secondary install failed with "Unknown error has occured"

Tags: centos, system-installation, ssd, hp

Bought an HPE Proliant Microserver Gen10 Plus and added a Kingston A2000 M.2 SSD drive with an adapter where I wanted to install the OS.
A "regular" SATA disk was planned to hold my data.

Installation went just fine, but I didn't allocate all the disk when installing, so opened `fdisk` to add a partition from the remaining disk --> the start of my troubles.

I *falsely* tought the default parameters when adding the disk were good-to-go, but sadly they weren't and the partition table of the SSD was destroyed.

No worries thought I, start the install again, and lo-and-behold - hours of retrying the install.

- Centos 8.2 gave the trusty "Pane is dead" error.
- Centos 8.3 gave the new "Unknown error has occured" - with some extra info `anaconda 33.16.3.26 dasbus`

I tried the boot and minimum install ISO, I tried half a dozen boot options, to no avail.
So where did this problem lie.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Anaconda does not like to scan disks with faulty partition tables.
In my ignorance I thought "just let me start installing and I'll fix it", but since the installation would not even *start* that was a no-go.

I knew that the SSD *might* be the issue, so I removed it (in the end...) and re-started the install. And now the Install actually started.

So in with the SSD again and...

In the end I booted the ISO in rescue mode.
Up with `fdisk` - create a partition and then - the crucial part - I added a file system to that partition and *now* the install finally started.
I used `mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p1` - but I really don't think it matters *what* just that there was a "real" partition table there again.

Still Anaconda complained when I tried to manually partition the disk, so in the end I went with the Automatic partitioning - which went fine.
Additional answer might perhaps shed light on what *more* to fix - but at least now my server is installed.

Hope this helps somebody down the road.